# LNK 2019- microsoft visual studdio

Tags: opengl, lnk2019

Hello I keep running into a recurring error. I managed to successfully link to the SDL library and my code was compiling with no problems, I then used the same procedure to link to an openGL(GLEW) library to use simultaneously with my project. The IDE recognized the GLEW library and all of its members appeared in the intellisense so the link was technically successful but when I try to compile I run into a LNK 2019 unresolved external symbol error for all of the openGL members. Any help or insight to the problem would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> The IDE recognized the GLEW library and all of its members appeared in the intellisense so the link was technically successful

No. That does not mean that you did sucessfully link it. It just means that IntelliSense read the header file and that's it. Linking is the very last step of building a program.

Getting a unresolved symbol linker error means, that of all the different compiled building blocks that make a program, not all that are necessary for the final product have been given to the linker. See your project build options, linker section and make sure all relevant libraries are passed to the linker.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Compiler/Linker/Libraries/Configuring_Visual_Studio